# Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey quickstart-webapp

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, jersey

I am trying to create a Maven based Jersey quick starter web App. I am selecting the glassfish archetype. But it is giving me the error given below. It is successfully creating com.sun.jersey archetype project. But with glassfish one its having issues. There are no proxy setup in my laptop which could interfere in downloading process. I need to sort this out asap.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey quickstart-webapp:2.19 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.19
Failure to transfer org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.19 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.19 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Failure to transfer org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.19 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:jar:2.19 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a typo error in the archetype's artifact: there is a missing hyphen. It's "jersey-quickstart-webapp" and not "jersey quickstart-webapp".

But there is also a timeout from Maven Central, so may be it was only that MC was not available at the time of transfert.

Whatever, before any new trial, delete the folders:
- ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/archetypes/jersey quickstart-webapp
- ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/archetypes/jersey-quickstart-webapp

Comment: Thanks @atao. It worked after deleting the folders as you specified.
This problem was coming when I was using local maven repository for archetypes. It can also be solved by using a Remote Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got the solution in eclipse

```
    1. Go to window.
    2. Select Preferences.
    3. Select Maven.
    4. Select Archetypes
    5. Add remote catalog.
    6. catalog file :- [http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml][1]   
    Description :- Remote Archetype (You can mention your own) 
    7. Click on verify and it should say something like this 
                 Found 27166 archetype(s)
    8. Click on OK.
    9. Restart your eclipse.


  [1]: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to window.

   2. Select Preferences.
   3. Select Maven.
   4. Select Archetypes
   5. Add remote catalog.
   6. catalog file :- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
      Description :- Remote Archetype (You can mention your own)
   7. Click on OK.

Answer (score 0):

on eclipse
Go to window.
Select Preferences.
Select Maven.
Select Archetypes
Add remote catalog.
catalog file :- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description :- Remote Archetype (You can mention your own)
Click on OK.